# format month and year in dropdown ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a dropdown with year and month populated in it.

The code is working but has some limitations. I am unable to add 0 to month field and unable to get last 2 numbers of year field.

Moreover, select month and allowed blank with required is also not working.

**Month Code:**

```
 <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers_true: true}, {name: nil, id: 
"month_num", :required => true, :include_blank => "Select Month"} %>
```

**Output:**

```
<select include_blank="Select Month" required="required" id="month_num">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

In above need to add: `01, 02, 03` like this in option value side not `1, 2, 3...`.

**Year Code:**

```
<%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: 
Date.today.year+10}, {name: nil, id: "year_num", :required => true,
 :include_blank => "Select Year"} %>
```

**Output:**

```
<select include_blank="Select Year" required="required" id="year_num">
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
<option value="2026">2026</option>
</select>
```

In above need to add: `16, 17, 18` like this in option value side not `2016, 2017, 2018...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as expected

```
<%= select_tag "month", options_for_select((1..12).map {|m| [Date::MONTHNAMES[m], format('%02d', m)]}), :required => true, :include_blank => "Select Month" %>  
<%= select_tag "year", options_for_select((Date.today.year..(Date.today.year + 10)).map {|m| [m, m % 100]}), :required => true, :include_blank => "Select Year" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.strftime("%y").to_i, end_year: (Date.today+10.years).strftime("%y").to_i}, {name: nil, id: "year_num", :required => true, :include_blank => "Select Year"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`select_month` or `select_year` doesn't accept custom `value` for `<option>` tag.

One option is to use `select_tag` with `options_for_select`.

```
# <select> tag for month names
<%= select_tag :month_num, options_for_select(Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.map{ |month, index| [month, '%02d' % (index + 1)] }) %>


# <select> tag for years
<%= select_tag :year_num, options_for_select((Date.today.year..(Date.today + 10.years).year).map{ |year| [year, '%02d' % (year % 100)] }, '%02d' % (Date.today.year % 100)) %>
```